# PHPUnit Selenium - can't find element by CSS

Tags: php, selenium, phpunit, automated-tests

I am using selenium to test our software, but I have run into a problem.
There is a button like this :

```html
<button data-action="show-more" class="btn btn-link btn-invisible more padded">Viac potenciálne zmluvy...</button>
```

And I am trying to select it with

```
$this->webDriver->findElement(WebDriverBy::cssSelector("btn.btn-link.btn-invisible.more.padded"));
```

And it just doesn't work. I have tried deleting some of the classes or using className - still nothing.

What am I doing wrong ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part of your selector is "btn" which is a class so it should be ".btn". I would go one step further and add the tag name to the front to make it a little more specific which would make the selector:

```
"button.btn.btn-link.btn-invisible.more.padded"
```

Comment: nice answer, awesome

Answer (score 2):

I think using following `cssSelector` would be more specific to locate desire element as :-

```
$this->webDriver->findElement(WebDriverBy::cssSelector("button.btn.btn-link.more[data-action='show-more']"));
```